# Update data using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my view for editcar :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<J2V.Models.vehicule>" %>
//code
<% using (Html.BeginForm("editcar", "Agence", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "search_form" })) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>vehicule</legend>
        // Those colonne will not be modified
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Matv) %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Idag) %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Idcat) %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idmarque) %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.modele) %>

        //Colonne to edit code

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

This is my controller action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult editcar(Models.vehicule model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            entity.vehicule.AddObject(model);
            entity.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            return View("index", new { id = model.Idag });
        }
        else
            return View();
}
```

When I click on the `Update` button I get this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<> f__AnonymousType2 `1 [System.String]' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` 1 [J2V.Models.vehicule] '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally an 'index' view's model is an `IEnumerable<YourModel>`.
But after updating, you are pushing an anonymous object into the 'index' view; (line: *`return View("index", new { id = model.Idag });`*) This might be the cause of the exception.

You may redirect to the index action:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        entity.vehicule.AddObject(model);
        entity.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        entity.SaveChanges();
        //return View("index", new { id = model.Idag });
        return RedirectToAction("index", new { id = model.Idag });
    }
    else
        return View();
```

Hope this helps...